# Checkbox for sharing feature

Tags: android, checkbox, default

How to extend the sharing feature with checkbox for default app?

here is my code:

```
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, developers);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
```

and the screencast herefor (without checkbox):

[image]

I want to make posible to set one app as default app.

Comment: Why do you want to reimplement something that is already built into the the system? What is the difference between what you want to do and what the system already does?

Comment: I want nothing reimplement. I want to make it possible that user set his default app.

Comment: Have you tested it on other devices? It should display the checkbox by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + developers[0]));
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, developers);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
activity.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

the line:

```
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + developers[0]));
```

Comment: would you explain what this does?

Answer (score 1):

Looking around I found this piece of documentation about the Intent flag ACTION_CHOOSER: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER

Here it states that:

> **This can be used as an alternative to
>   the standard activity picker that is
>   displayed by the system when you try
>   to start an activity with multiple
>   possible matches, with these
>   differences in behavior**: You can
>   specify the title that will appear in
>   the activity chooser. **The user does
>   not have the option to make one of the
>   matching activities a preferred
>   activity**, and all possible activities
>   will always be shown even if one of
>   them is currently marked as the
>   preferred activity.

The text in bold says that the system displays a checkbox by default unless otherwise specified by the developer, for example by using the flag ACTION_CHOOSER.

I don't know why your system does something else.